# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'SUPPORT_WL_SERVER_CHANGE' in null

Tags: javascript, firefox, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

- Update - I originally posted with the firefox error, the chrome error message is more useful, so I've updated its name

(firefox) - invalid 'in' operand profile in worklight.js

(chrome) -  TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'SUPPORT_WL_SERVER_CHANGE' in null

I have seen similar questions to this, none have been answered, and none provided all the code needed to reproduce the results.

I get differing messages with firefox and chrome. so i updated the title to show both.

to reproduce:

create a new worklight project, and application in that project
create a new HTTP adapter, call it myRESTAdapter

replace index.html with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular_test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=0">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
<script>
        function mobGmapLatLng(pAddress) {
            var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'myRESTAdapter',
                    procedure : 'getGmapLatLng',
                    parameters : [ pAddress ]
                };

            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
                onSuccess : function(result){
                    console.debug("good");
                    var httpStatusCode = result.status;
                    if (200 == httpStatusCode) {
                        var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
                        var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
                        if (true == isSuccessful) {
                            var lat = invocationResult.lat;
                            var lng = invocationResult.lng;
                            alert("Success: lat=" + lat + " lng=" + lng);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error. isSuccessful=" + isSuccessful);
                        }                    
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode);
                    }
                },
                onFailure : function(result){
                    console.debug("bad");
                }
            });
        }

</script>   
</head>
<body>
    Hello Worklight with getGmapLatLng
<p>
<button onclick="mobGmapLatLng( '11501 Burnet Rd, Austin, TX, USA' )">Austin, TX, USA</button>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="mobGmapLatLng( '4250 South Miami Boulevard, Durham, NC, USA' )">Durham, NC, USA</button>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="mobGmapLatLng( '1681 Route des Dolines, 06560 Valbonne, France' )">Valbonne, France</button>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="mobGmapLatLng( 'Shefayim 60990, Israel' )">Shefayim, Israel</button>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="mobGmapLatLng( '399 Ke Yuan Lu, Shanghai, China' )">Shanghai, China</button>
</p>                        
</body>
</html>
```

next in your adapter replace myRESTAdapter.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wl:adapter name="myRESTAdapter"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

<displayName>myRESTAdapter</displayName>
<description>myRESTAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>http://maps.googleapis.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getGmapLatLng"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

and replace myRESTAdapater-impl.js with:

```
function getGmapLatLng(pAddress) {
var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : 'maps/api/geocode/json',
    parameters : {
        'address' : 'plaza 3 one nationwide blvd columbus oh',
        'sensor' : 'false'   // hard-coded
    }
};

var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

// Extract latitude and longitude from the response.
var type = typeof response; 
if ("object" == type) {
    if (true == response["isSuccessful"]) {

        // Drill down into the response object.
        var results = response["results"];
        var result = results[0];
        var geometry = result["geometry"];
        var location = geometry["location"];

        // Return JSON object with lat and lng.
        return location;
    } 
    else {
        // Returning null. Web request was not successful.
        return null;
    }
} 
else {
    // Returning null. Response is not an object.
    return null;
}
}
```

right click on index.html and select Run As-> preview
open firebug so you can see error messages: invalid 'in' operand profile in worklight.js 
click on one of the buttons and you'll see the error message in firebug

*** note: I had to make some changes so this would work behind a corp firewall, i think it should paste and run, but I can't test it currently as it is.

** note 2: i'm almost positive I've had this exact code run successfully before, and I can't figure out why it feels like sometimes I get the error, and sometimes it works

tested with worklight 6.3.0
the adapter code functions correctly, and returns the correct data when I call it with run as->invoke mobilefirst procedure

line number: 5059 in worklight.js

Comment: Does the error give you a line number?

Comment: Yes, also add the error you get as well as mention the Worklight version you are using.

Comment: Using MFP 6.3 and previewing the app in Chrome I do not get this error.

Comment: Might be because is something is off in your adapter code; I'm getting Failed to parse JSON string on the server logs. But not the mentioned error.

Comment: see if answer to this question helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611058/how-to-make-https-requests-with-serverside-javascript-using-worklight/11627300

Comment: to clarify, the above adapter code works fine for me. I can call it and get the right data back, it is only when I call it from the app that I get the error message.

Comment: I run it in chrome and do not get this error... If there are specific steps to follow, please mention them. Also I suggest to supply an actual zip with the project instead.

Answer (score 2):

I rebuilt the project, and got it working, when looking at the differences between the working one, and mine this is the section of code I was missing in the original code:

```
<script>
    var wlInitOptions = {
    };

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {      
            WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { 
            WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to include initOptions.js which contains this code. After including it, It worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I noted this post and actually keep your heads up for an iFix which is now rolling : (PI63389).
Such TypeError in that line should not stop the application anymore.